# Change Number string 1000000 to 1.000.000

Tags: php, string, numbers, units-of-measurement

Using PhP I want to make my numbers more 'readable'...

I want to modify for example:

- 10 ... 10 (no change)
- 100 would be 100 (still no change)
- 1000 would be 1.000
- 1.000.000 would be 1.000.000
- 1000000000 would be 1.000.000.000 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)**

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`NumberFormatter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php).

Answer (score 2):

```
$number = 1000000000000.4568;
$str_num = number_format( $number, 2, '.', '.' );

// $str_num Output
1.000.000.000.000.46
```